# I am having error while trying top add a divider between my v-list items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am getting an error on :key="index" in  that said  key should be placed on the  tag. Can any please suggest a slution.

```html
<template v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys">
  <v-list-item :key="index">
      <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
          {{ key }} :
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-content class="align-end" :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
          {{ item[key.toLowerCase()] }}
      </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
  <v-divider v-if="index < filteredKeys.length - 1" :key="`${index}-divider`"></v-divider>
</template>
```

Comment: Does it not work to follow the instructions of the error and move `:key="index"` to the template tag?

Comment: Here, you can check when to use the index on the template and when on elements- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74811111/print-element-after-component-at-some-point-when-iterating-through-array-in-vue/74813328#74813328

Comment: @yoduh no it did not work