# Print element after component at some point when iterating through array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using a for-loop on the `component` element and when the loop's third iteration comes, I want to display a `<p>` element which is just next to the `<component>` element.

The problem is that to access the iteration variable `i`, the `<p>` element should be part of the loop but the loop is running on the `<component>` and there is no way to move `<p>` inside the `<component>`.

I have no idea how to access the iteration to the `<p>` element.

Here is my code-

```
<div class="grid">
            <component
                :is="item.component"
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :index="i"
                :key="item.id"
                :image="item.image"
                :to="item.to"
                :image-secondary="item.imageSecondary"
                :title="item.title"
                :date="item.date"
                :talent="item.talent"
                :excerpt="item.excerpt"
                class="block"
            />
            <p v-if="i === 2">PRINTED AFTER 3RD COMPONENT</p>
        </div>
```

I also think about detaching and attaching it with JS but I don't find it a good practice.
I also think about doing this In PHP something like this-

```
if($items){
$count = 0;
 foreach($items as $item){
  echo $item;
  if($count == 2){
   echo '<p>some text</p>';
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your p tag is outside the v-for loop. [See documentation about v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for).

Notice how we move the v-for to include both elements, this guarantees that the p tag receives `i`.

```
<div class="grid">
  <template v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="item.id">
     <component
       :is="item.component"
       :index="i"
       :image="item.image"
       :to="item.to"
       :image-secondary="item.imageSecondary"
       :title="item.title"
       :date="item.date"
       :talent="item.talent"
       :excerpt="item.excerpt"
       class="block"
     />
     <p v-if="i === 2">PRINTED AFTER 3RD COMPONENT</p>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i knew it was outside the loop, but didn't know how to put it inside the loop but outside the component... 
I did not know about the <template> tag! Thanks.
Using your example, i get this error: <template> cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-on-template)-

**"Similar to template `v-if`, you can also use a `<template>` tag with `v-for` to render a block of multiple elements."**

On another note, If you are using `Vue.js 2.x`, a template cannot be keyed, so, You need to key every child accordingly.

```
<div class="grid">
    <template v-for="(item, i) in items">
        <component
            :key="'component' + i"
            :is="item.component"
            :index="i"
            :image="item.image"
            :to="item.to"
            :image-secondary="item.imageSecondary"
            :title="item.title"
            :date="item.date"
            :talent="item.talent"
            :excerpt="item.excerpt"
            class="block"
        />
        <p v-if="i === 2" :key="'paragraph' + i">PRINTED AFTER 3RD COMPONENT</p>
    </template>
</div>
```

But if you are using `Vue.js 3.x`, with the support for fragments, the `<template v-for>` key can be placed on the `<template>` tag.

```
<div class="grid">
    <template v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
        <component
            :is="item.component"
            :index="i"
            :image="item.image"
            :to="item.to"
            :image-secondary="item.imageSecondary"
            :title="item.title"
            :date="item.date"
            :talent="item.talent"
            :excerpt="item.excerpt"
            class="block"
        />
        <p v-if="i === 2">PRINTED AFTER 3RD COMPONENT</p>
    </template>
</div>
```

for more information, read here- https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#with-template-v-for

Comment: Thanks! If I use the key on component, i get an error: "<template v-for> key should be placed on the <template> tag." And if I key the template, i get "template can't be keyed" :/ Any Idea?

Comment: What is your vue version?

Comment: I edited the answer for both Vue versions, as you did not mention the version in your question, so I posted previously only for Vue 2.x.